# Generalization of Whittaker–Shannon for Functions with Countably Infinite Information in Finite Interval?

Tags: information-theory

Are there any continuous, bounded, functions that are smooth but with countably many discontinuities that be reconstructed only by capturing a countably infinite sequence of samples over a finite interval? If so, how would the reconstruction be done?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Devil's staircase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function)?  Also, do you require exact reconstruction, uniformly bounded error, or some other inexact reconstruction?

Comment: @EricTowers exact please. I will check out devil’s staircase.